# XDebuger (Cannot send session cookie...)

Tags: php, sublime-text, xdebug

Настроил себе недавно **XDebuger** в редакторе ***SubimeText 3*** все работало нормально - проект тот же, лок. сервер ***OpenServer***. 
Сегодня запускаю отладку скрипта и выдает конфликт в отправке сесии.
Как можно решить эту проблему?

> [Warning] session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers
>   already sent by

...указывает на место вывода контента: `echo $content;`
**Т.е.** все сесии и прочие кукис уже отработали - начинаем вывод. Почему ссесия **XDebuger**-а ещё не сработала?

Comment: http://www.php.su/forum/topic.php?forum=1&topic=3026

Comment: @Visman к сожалению, не срабатывает такой вот трюк у меня 8*(

Answer (score 1):

Это один из тех вопросов, ответ на который можно получить самостоятельно.

Для этого надо всего лишь *дочитать сообщение об ошибке до конца.* Там всё написано.

сообщения об ошибках вообще полезно читать. Обычно там написано не просто "Ой, беда-беда, насяльника, нисиво ни работаит!" а даётся **подробное описание** - что конкретно и почему не работает.

в данном случае, после слов "output started in" пишется имя файла и строка, в которой был инициирован вывод. И пользователю остаётся всего лишь открыть нужный файл и посмотреть глазами, что именно в этой строке выводится.

Если строка первая и ничего не видно - значит это BOM.

Comment: Я писал (выше), что в "указаном месте вывода контента (содержимое html страницы): echo $content;". До этого места ничего не выводится 100%. Прямо перед этим местом отправил заголовок - сработал. Данные, что выводятся с переменной, действительно содержат пустой перенос строки вначале - разве может echo из файла UTF-8 без BOM выводить другую кодировку?)